# ViewModel or View responsibility in draw logic

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-viewmodel

Yesterday I had a little discussion with one of my work partners about ViewModel and View responsibility. I have a text that changes in different contexts, like Edit/New mode in the View. One of the team programmers wrote somthing like this:

```
@if (Model.IsNew)
{
    @Resources.New;
}
else
{
    @(Resources.Editing + " " + Model.Name);
}
```

I defend that this logic is ViewModel responsibility:

In the ViewModel:

```
public string PageTitle => IsNew ? Resources.New : $"{Resources.Editing} {Name}";
```

Then in the View:

```
<h2>
    @Model.PageTitle
</h2>
```

But my colleage defends who that is a print logic, so the View has the responsibility.

Both of us have our arguments, but I would like to know the community opinion.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you look up the definiton of [MVC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model%E2%80%93view%E2%80%93controller) pattern, you can see that:

> A view generates new output to the user based on changes in the model.

Means that if you want to adhere to the [Separation of Concerns](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Separation_of_concerns) principle properly, the view is responsible for displaying the data in the UI, the model stands for as a property bag of data you will bring to view.

So basically the underlying model of your view is your viewmodel, and by this I would put this property into the viewmodel and the logic that sets it to the controller/viewmodel builder/service/whatever fits your needs.

To further defend this, ask your collegue how easy would that be to unit/integaration test the code in the view? Bringing a new test just for asserting a the outcome this logic? Brings no real business value to me...

To extend this subject further to keep the concerns separated you could:

- Create very thin and focused controllers for modes, such as new, edit, etc.
- Separate viewmodels per these modes, so your viewmodels are in 1-1 relations to views.

Although all these are opinionated, make sure to create an environment that fits everyone.

Answer (score 1):

I'd say that this piece of logic is more related to the View - since we are talking about page **title**.

But instead of creating nested statements I'd create an Html helper for this, f.i. `Html.PageTitle(Model)`.

Comment: Disagree with this. Not every ViewModel will have an IsNew property. Do you think he should make a helper for every page? KEEP IT SIMPLE - place code on ViewModel where its at least testable.

Answer (score 1):

Its ViewModel code, completely agree with Kayess. Views should not have to figure out what they display.

Seeing @{ } all over a view send shivers up my spine. Its always buggy, untestable code.